# Unable to get element

Tags: jquery, html

Im using Jquery to select an HTML object from my site.

```
<div id="banner">
  <!-- stuff in here -->
</div>
```

Im using this code:

```
$(window).load($(function()
{
    var elem = $("#banner");
    var top = elem.offset().top;
    var maxTop = $("#footer").offset().top - elem.height();
    var scrollHandler = function()
    {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollTop<top) {
        elem.css({position:"relative",top:""})
      } else if (scrollTop>maxTop) {
        elem.css({position:"absolute",top:(maxTop+"px")})
      } else {
        elem.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
      }
    }
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);scrollHandler()

}));
```

However I keep getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

For some reason, its not seeing the div 'banner'.

Any idea why?

Edit:

Per a suggestion below, I changed the code from $(window).load to $(document).ready. Still same issue.

```
$(document).ready($(function()
{
    var elem = $("#banner");
    var top = elem.offset().top;
    var maxTop = $("#footer").offset().top - elem.height();
    var scrollHandler = function()
    {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scrollTop<top) {
        elem.css({position:"relative",top:""})
      } else if (scrollTop>maxTop) {
        elem.css({position:"absolute",top:(maxTop+"px")})
      } else {
        elem.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
      }
    }
    $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);scrollHandler()

}));
```

Comment: Hint: $(document).ready, not $(window).load

Comment: That's a lot of code just to get an element.

Comment: It could also be that what is not seeing is the #footer div.

Comment: $(document).ready($(function()  supposed to be $(document).ready(function()

Comment: And you can replace $(document).ready with $(function() { /* all other code here */ });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load($(function()   // Passing a jQuery Object Here
```

Supposed to be

```
$(window).load( function()   //
```

If this does not work replace it with

```
$(document).ready( function()
```

Answer (score 3):

You're passing in a jQuery object to your load function instead of a function. Try removing the $() around the main callback. e.g.

```
$(window).load(function()
{
var elem = $("#banner");
var top = elem.offset().top;
var maxTop = $("#footer").offset().top - elem.height();
var scrollHandler = function()
{
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scrollTop<top) {
    elem.css({position:"relative",top:""})
  } else if (scrollTop>maxTop) {
    elem.css({position:"absolute",top:(maxTop+"px")})
  } else {
    elem.css({position:"fixed",top:"0px"})
  }
}
$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);scrollHandler()

});
```

Note: There's nothing **wrong** per se with using $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready() as some people here are suggesting. The second is more idiomatic because it executes earlier (letting users interact with your page faster). See this link for details: http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/